# Name of design pattern for method which does nothing but throw an exception upon a condition?

Tags: function, exception, design-patterns, methods

I've came across code with functions which do nothing except check a conditional and throw an exception or do nothing depending on the outcome of the evaluation of the conditional.

The code would look something like this:

```cs
public string MyMethod() {
    var name = "foo";
    EnsureSuccess(name);
    return name;
}

// Throws an exception if name is not "bar"
public void EnsureSuccess(string name) {
    if (name != "bar")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not bar!");
    }
}
```

What is this called? Is this a named design pattern?

Also is this considered a good practice or a bad practice?

Example of code in the wild that uses this is the `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` method in `HttpResponseMessage.cs` which is part of `System.Net.Http` by Microsoft. ([code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs#L117), [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode%28v=vs.118%29.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

That's not a design pattern. It's called [programming assertion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development))

> In computer programming, an assertion is a predicate (a true–false
>   statement) placed in a program to indicate that the developer thinks
>   that the predicate is always true at that place. If an assertion
>   evaluates to false at run-time, an assertion failure results, which
>   typically causes execution to abort.

Comment: Is assertions used in this way? I thought assertions were only used for unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the @Chris Eelmaa answer, I'll say that also [Don't_repeat_yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle is used. Seems that `EnsureSuccess(string name)` is being used a lot..otherwise I don't see the point of extracting 2 lines of code.

Another interesting thing in the example is not like you pointed

```
throw new Exception("Not bar!");
```

But according to the [MSDN Best Practices for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx) - *Don't throw new Exception()*

So please note that should be

```
throw new SpecificException("Not bar!");
```

Exception is a too broad class, and it's hard to catch without side-effects. Derive your own exception class, but derive it from *Exception*. This way you could set a specialized exception handler for exceptions thrown by the framework and another for exceptions thrown by yourself.

In the code example they are:

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ();
throw new ArgumentNullException ("......");
throw new HttpRequestException (string.Format ("{0} ({1})", (int) statusCode, ReasonPhrase));
```

Comment: That particular advice about [`ApplicationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) dates from the 1.0/1.1 era (IIRC). These days it notes: "You should derive custom exceptions from the [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) class rather than the ApplicationException class. You should not throw an ApplicationException exception in your code, and you should not catch an ApplicationException exception unless you intend to re-throw the original exception."

Comment: I knew not to catch the general exception, but since this was just an example, I didn't use any more specific exception. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the code of `EnsureSuccess` being in-line at `MyMethod`:

```cs
public string MyMethod() {
    var name = "foo";
    // Ensure success
    if (name != "bar")
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Not bar!");
    }
    return name;
}
```

First, it would require a comment to explain what it's doing. Second, as [pointed out before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26229583/1168342), you'd be repeating this code at every place you need to check this condition.

There's a refactoring (which is like a coding pattern) called [extract method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) that results in what you see here.

Extract method (in this case, 'Don't repeat yourself') is also an example of [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding), since the details of `EnsureSuccess` are hidden away in that method. If ever a decision was made to change the logic of how `EnsureSuccess` works, one only changes the single method, and everywhere that calls the method will not need changing.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial code and I actually refactored it using extract method. I was wondering if this type of code is called something.

Answer (score 0):

It might be Visitor, where you put the functions in a class.
So maybe that class EnsureSuccess would act as some kind of validator.
Maybe this class' jobs are to execute all the exception handlings?

It can also be a Facade pattern.
This pattern is very common used as a validator.

Thank you,

Comment: The code has no classes or interfaces or such, so it does not really look like the Visitor pattern or the Facade pattern to me.

Comment: Then, it might be just simply refactoring. It is useful when the you have long winded codes to get everything looks clean and readable. Otherwise, you will get crazy when you want to do bug fix.

Comment: Refactoring is just a process that you do. I was wondering if this specific way of arranging code is called anything.